# Adding metadata to words in word2vec

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I have a word2vec model and I want to change it by adding some additional data beside the occurrence of the word itself.

For example:

Category (out of predefined 50), POS etc.

I thought of two ways to do it:

1. Just concat the metadata to the word. (so that the word "desk" will be coded as "desk-furniture-Noun"
2. The better way in my opinion: Create a new loss function that will be a function of the co-occurrences of the word itself, the co-occurrences of the category, the co-occurrences POS, etc.

So my questions are:
1. What will be a better way?
2. How can I create a new loss function and optimize it in Word2Vec? Can I just pass a parameter to Gensim's Word2Vec or do I need to build a new Word2vec model from scratch?